# Two way scrollable carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

- In my html application, I want a n*n grid and show only a portion of
  it at any time.
- Each tile displays html content and not images.
- The user can scroll horizontally or vertically by one row or column.
- When a new tile loads on the map, it should load content via
  ajax.

I went though a number of js libraries of different categories carousels, tile engines, map rendering libraries and ...

Libraries in each category are missing one thing or the other.

- Carousels - Two way scrolling and grid is not there
- Tile engines - Asynchronous loading of a tile not available.
- Map renderers - Support only layers/images.

Suggest me an appropriate library that will best fit this requirement.

Comment: try this https://github.com/cubiq/2-way-iScroll\

Comment: Looks good. There isn't any onshow for any html tags where I can load the contents via ajax when they appear on the screen. Have to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try using iScroll.js it will work

```
<script src="http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/src/iscroll.js"></script>
<div id="vertical">
    <div id="vert_scroller">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var HTML = "";
        for(i=0;i < 10;i++){
            HTML += '<div id="sc'+i+'" class="innerWrap"><div class="innerSc"><span>'+(Math.random()*64654).toString()+'</span></div></div>';
        }
        $("#vert_scroller").html(HTML);
        myScroll = new iScroll('vertical');
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            innerScroll_1 = new iScroll('sc'+i);
        }
    })
</script>


    #vertical{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    z-index:1;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
}

#vert_scroller{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.innerWrap{
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.innerSc{
    padding:10px;
    width:450px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```